# Accelerometer fix values

Tags: arduino-uno, accelerometer

I use Arduino Uno with an Accelerometer ADXL345-gy-291 (the full name of the ship) i did hook it up like this 
[image]

Note I'm using SPI Communication, that was the right one to use in my case. 
when I plug in my Arduino here what does my serial monitor give me 
[image]

as you can see, it sends back fixed values no matter the movement of the ship is. 
the code I use is :

```
#include <SparkFun_ADXL345.h>        
ADXL345 adxl = ADXL345(10);      

void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);               
  Serial.println("SparkFun ADXL345 Accelerometer Hook Up Guide Example");
  Serial.println();
  adxl.powerOn();                   
  adxl.setRangeSetting(16);         
  adxl.setSpiBit(0);
  adxl.setActivityXYZ(1, 0, 0);
  adxl.setActivityThreshold(75);
  adxl.setInactivityXYZ(1, 0, 0);
  adxl.setInactivityThreshold(75);
  adxl.setTimeInactivity(10);
  adxl.setTapDetectionOnXYZ(0, 0, 1);
  adxl.setTapThreshold(50);
  adxl.setTapDuration(15);
  adxl.setDoubleTapLatency(80);
  adxl.setDoubleTapWindow(200);
  adxl.setFreeFallThreshold(7);
  adxl.setFreeFallDuration(30);
  adxl.InactivityINT(1);
  adxl.ActivityINT(1);
  adxl.FreeFallINT(1);
  adxl.doubleTapINT(1);
  adxl.singleTapINT(1);
}
void loop(){
  int x,y,z;   
  adxl.readAccel(&x, &y, &z);
  Serial.print(x);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print(y);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.println(z); 
  ADXL_ISR();
}
void ADXL_ISR() {
  byte interrupts = adxl.getInterruptSource();

  if(adxl.triggered(interrupts, ADXL345_FREE_FALL)){
    Serial.println("*** FREE FALL ***");
  } 

  if(adxl.triggered(interrupts, ADXL345_INACTIVITY)){
    Serial.println("*** INACTIVITY ***");
  }

  if(adxl.triggered(interrupts, ADXL345_ACTIVITY)){
    Serial.println("*** ACTIVITY ***"); 
  }

  if(adxl.triggered(interrupts, ADXL345_DOUBLE_TAP)){
    Serial.println("*** DOUBLE TAP ***");
  }


  if(adxl.triggered(interrupts, ADXL345_SINGLE_TAP)){
    Serial.println("*** TAP ***");
  } 
}
```

so I wonder what was the mistake I made there?

Answer (score 1):

You need to level-shift the Arduino's 5V signals to the module's I/O range of 1.7 - 3.6 V if you want to use SPI; that is, if you haven't damaged it already. I suggest you follow the tutorial [here](http://forum.hobbycomponents.com/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=1568) though. It employs I2C instead of SPI but is specific to your particular module. There are no level-shifters needed in this case. Simply connect VCC and CS to 3.3 V, the I2C pins to 3.3 V through 4.7k pull-ups and the GNDs together.

Comment: Those modules from Sparkfun and from Chinese suppliers already include a voltage regulator, accepting from 2.0-2.5V to 5-6V Vcc.